# Regex match anything except two specific strings (angular/cli 7.3.5, types/node 8.9.4)

Tags: node.js, regex, angular

I am using a regex expression to validate an input. I would like to match the exact strings "spe1" and "spe1.grl".

So far I have written the following code:

```
'\\b(?!i' + this.stringToIgnore + '\\b)\\w+';
```

where this.stringToIgnore = 'spe1'

this work if I type:

> "spe1 " (note the space)
>
> "spe1."

I would like to have a match as soon as I type:

> "spe1" (without the need to add a space or dot at the end)
>
> "spe1.grl" (without the need to add a space or dot at the end)

Thank you for your help

Comment: why do you have `\w+` at the end of your regex? if you remove that, it should work as you want.

Comment: Dear mankowitz, thank you for attempting to answer my question. Unfortunately your solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

After palying a bit with an online Regex tool I have find the answer to my own question. I am posting it in case someone needs it:

```
'\\b(?!' + this.stringToIgnore + '\\b)\\w+';
```

or

```
''\\b(?!' + this.stringToIgnore + '|' + this.stringToIgnore.toUpperCase + '\\b)\\w+';
```

in case the user has the uppercase key on.